# How to perform operation when a message is sent to dead letter queue because of expiration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-rabbit

I have a requirement where I want to perform some operation with the message (like sending the message to the support team or logging the message in the console) when a message expires and is sent to the dead letter queue. Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: Read the DLQ and do something with the messages.

Comment: There are 2 issues with it - how do I identify the messages which are in DLQ for timeout and not for NACK reasons (NACK because of some error)? And I don't want the messages to be removed from DLQ.

Comment: Examine the x-death header; it has that information.